# Why do I get unary operator expected?

Tags: bash, syntax

So I am busy creating a rm function or I guess that is what it's called.
After executing the script and typing rm I get this error:

```
bash: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

My code is:

```sh
rm(){
if[ "$@" == "-u" ];
then
  echo "Do something amazing."
else
 echo "Boring"
}
```

I have even tried replacing the == with -eq but I still get the same error.

How to fix this?

P.S. when I type rm -u I don't get the error the code runs fine.

Comment: check your code here : https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `-eq` is for comparing integers, not strings. Also, in a `[ ]` test, `=` is the standard string equality operator. bash and some other shells allow `==` as a synonym, but not all do; and if you're writing specifically for bash, `[[ ]]` is generally better than `[ ]` (fewer sharp edges in the syntax).

Answer (score 4):

`"$@"` expands to all the arguments of the function, each separately requoted. If there are no arguments, it expands to an empty string, and the `if` statement becomes.

```
if [ == "-u" ]
```

which is not valid because there's nothing before `==`. You would also get an error if you gave multiple arguments to the function; if you do `rm -x -y` it becomes

```
if [ "-x" "-y" == "-u" ]
```

Use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"` to get all the arguments as a single string.